# R and Maple optimization comparison

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, maple

I would like to maximize the following funcation both in Maple and R:

Firstly, let's do it in maple:

```
f := (1.98487000395764*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t))))/(1+exp(-2.*t))-.309660918271578*t*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t)))/(1+exp(-2.*t))+2.72769846075997*t^2*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t)))/(1+exp(-2.*t))+(6.98540143163400*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))-(.642949404838428*(t-1.))*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.)))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))+12.4616594684298*(t-1.)^2*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.)))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))-2:

plot(f, t = -5 .. 5)
```

[image: plot by maple]

```
NLPSolve(f, t = xL .. xU, method = branchandbound, maximize);
```

[image]

As can bee seen from the plot, global maximum is larger than 0, but maple returned 0 as a global maximum.
Now, let's try it in R by copying the exact function:

```
f.maple <- function(t){
  out <- (1.98487000395764*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t))))/(1+exp(-2.*t))-.309660918271578*t*    (1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t)))/(1+exp(-2.*t))+2.72769846075997*t^2*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t)))/(1+exp(-2.*t))+(6.98540143163400*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))-(.642949404838428*(t-1.))*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.)))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))+12.4616594684298*(t-1.)^2*(1-1/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.)))/(1+exp(-2.*t+2.))-2
  return(-out)
}
t = seq(lx, ux, by = .1)
plot(t, -f.maple(t), type = "l")
```

[image: R plot]

```
require(Rsolnp)  
res <- gosolnp(fun = f.maple, LB = lx, UB = ux, n.sim = 50, n.restarts = 1)

> res$par
[1] 0.1963055

> -res$values[3]
[1] 0.6511135
```

As can bee seen R gave  0.19631 as the maximum of the function which seems to be true:

```
 -f.maple(0)
 [1] 0.6055397

 -f.maple(0.1963055)
  0.6511135
```

I am a bit confused of Maple optimization procedure becasue 0 is even not a local maximum to be trapped and don't know why the maple optimization procedure return 0 instead of 0.1963055

Any hint would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Welcome. I also read the question and it might be a bug in maple. Unfortunately I don't have Maple on my machine so I cannot test it, sorry.

Comment: I don't know why the branch-and-bound method fails, but if you don't specify a method, then you'll get the same answer as with R. Note that Maple's NLPSolve never chooses branch-and-bound on its own, so I guess it's a highly specialized method. See help page ?Optimization,General,Methods .

Comment: @CarlLove  the Branch-and-Bound method is a global search procedure and usually it should find the global optimum for such simple functions with two maximums. 

The point is that if the wrong answer was a local maximum the failure could be accepted but here the answer even not a local one. the maple help documentation about this method is as following:
Branch-and-Bound (Global Search) -- This method is available for univariate problems with no general constraints but with finite bounds.

Comment: It worked for me in Maple 17 with the range t=-5..4.5 or t=-4.5..5, but failed as described for t=-5..5. Increasing the working precision (Digits) or additionally supplying the `nodelimit` option did not seem to help. I suspect a bug. I will submit a bug report.

Comment: I got the better solution at t=0.1963055 if I included the option `evaluationlimit=80` (or higher). The default for that limit is 50, and it appears to be in effect in at least a final (local optimizing) refinement step although I have not debugged to see how exactly it may be affecting the final result. I set `infolevel[Optimization]:=6` to reveal details.